# Portlet support in tellurium

Tags: java, portlet

Can Tellurium tool supports portlet testing because portlet gives dynamic and unique URL and it changes everytime when portlet renders?
Can somebody please help me finding this as I did not get clear information from internet.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It is dynamic and unique, but definitely can be templated and concluded. I did many kinds of tests with Liferay and JMeter. As I remember I needed to conclude one or two variables to create proper links.